# How are ints stored in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, integer, byte

I've been trying to understand how data is stored in C but I'm getting confused. I have this code:

```
 int main(){ 
 int a; 
 char *x; 
 x = (char *) &a; 
 x[0] = 0; 
 x[1] = 3;
 printf("%d\n", a); 
return 0; 
}
```

I've been messing around with x[0] & x[1], trying to figure out how they work, but I just can't. For example x[1] = 3 outputs 768. Why?

I understand that there are 4 bytes (each holding 8 bits) in an int, and x[1] points to the 2nd byte. But I don't understand how making that second byte equal to 3, means a = 768.

I can visualise this in binary format:

byte 1: 00000000

byte 2: 00000011

byte 3: 00000000

byte 4: 00000000

But where does the 3 come into play? how does doing byte 2 = 3, make it 00000011 or 768.

Additional question: If I was asked to store 545 in memory. What would a[0] and a[1] = ?

I know the layout in binary is:

byte 1: 00100001

byte 2: 00000010

byte 3: 00000000

byte 4: 00000000

Comment: 768 = 512 + 256 = 2^9 + 2^8... Does this help?

Comment: Note that on many machines these days, type `int` is 4 bytes (32 bits), so in your sample code, you'd want to add `x[2] = x[3] = 0;` for consistent results.

Comment: @SteveSummit ... or `int a = 0;` to emphasize the mantra "ALWAYS initialise variables" `:-)`

Comment: I still don't see where the 3 comes into play. But i think i figured out a method. Just write it out in binary form, then to convert it to denary by using the scale of the first byte (1,2,...128) for all bytes. So for 768, the 2nd byte is 00000011, this equals 3 on the scale of the first byte (1-128), so the 2nd byte = 3.

Comment: @compsci3289294 Let's say `a` is 4 bytes.  It is initially "undefined".  That means it could have any value.  That value could come from whatever previously occupied that spot on the stack, or a register, or whatever.  So you start with 4 garbage bytes.  You then set 2 of them.  The other 2 are still garbage.  It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

It is not specific to C, it is how your computer is storing the data.

There are two different methods called endianess.

1. Little-endian: the least significant byte is stored first.
   Example: `0x11223344` will be stored as `0x44 0x33 0x22 0x11`
2. Big-endian: the least significant byte is stored last.
   Example: `0x11223344` will be stored as `0x11 0x22 0x33 0x44`

Most modern computers use the little-endian system.

> Additional question: If I was asked to store 545 in memory

545 in hex is 0x221 so the first byte will be `0x21 and the second one 0x02` as your computer is little-endian.

Why do I use hex numbers? Because every two digits represent exactly one byte in memory.

> I've been messing around with x[0] & x[1], trying to figure out how
> they work, but I just can't. For example x[1] = 3 outputs 768. Why?

768 in hex is 0x300. So the byte representation is `0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00`

Comment: I think i found a method to get the bytes in denary form from binary form. For the first byte, it's simply that number. For the second byte, it's that number, but on the scale of the first byte (0-128), so if there's a 1 under 256, this equals 1. If there's a 1 under 512 this equals 2 etc. Is this correct? I need to use denary over hex for my current work.

Comment: @compsci3289294 `I think i found a method to get the bytes in denary` - do not waste your time. Use hex or octal numbers instead as all programmers . Try the same with 2882400069

Comment: Re "*There are two different methods called endianess*", There are three representations (two's complement, ones' complement, sign-magnitude) and more than two byte orders aka endianness. That is way more than "two methods".

Comment: @ikegami hot signed integers are stored is not related to this question. Mixed, middle endianess are so exotic and I never worked on the machine having it (40y programming experience).  Can you elaborate how signed integers format is related the the OP's question? And where are machines (abstracting maybe from some in the 50's) having those exotic endianess systems

Answer (score -1):

Warning: by casting the address of an `int` to a `char *`, the compiler is defenseless trying to maintain order. Casting is the programmer telling the compiler "I know what I am doing." Use it will care.

Another way to refer to the same region of memory in two different modes is to use a `union`. Here the compiler will allocate the space required that is addressable as either an `int` or an array of `signed char`.

This might be a simpler way to experiment with setting/clearing certain bits as you come to understand how the architecture of your computer stores multi-byte datatypes.

See other responses for hints about "endian-ness".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    union {
        int i;
        char c[4];
    } x;

    x.i = 0;
    x.c[1] = 3;
    printf( "%02x %02x %02x %02x %08x %d\n", x.c[0], x.c[1], x.c[2], x.c[3], x.i, x.i );

    x.i = 545;
    printf( "%02x %02x %02x %02x %08x %d\n", x.c[0], x.c[1], x.c[2], x.c[3], x.i, x.i );

    return 0;
}
```

```
00 03 00 00 00000300 768
21 02 00 00 00000221 545
```

Comment: You forgot about the most important and most portable way of type punning. BTW access as chars is not dangerous.

Comment: @0___________ "Access as chars is not dangerous"... Then why are do many newbies have to be informed about sign extension as the cause of their confusion... I didn't bother here because the salient point was "union", but only one of those 4 "chars" in my answer is "signed" in keeping with its bunkmate, the "signed int"... And, newbies like the OP aren't ready, yet, to begin to worry about "portability".

Comment: You forgot about memcpy method.

Comment: @0___________ Many ways to skin a cat... You're always free to add `memcpy()` to your answer.

Comment: But anyway - char access is safe, the other way is not.

Comment: I absolutely agree with this, if you are worried about portability and such, even if it is not unsafe there are correct ways to tackle issues in C, be it memcpy or union, union just so happens to be a formally correct way of a approaching the issue that is directly connected to an algebric way of representing data (haskell's either)